# Sending model boolean value to js function results in onchange function reference

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an onchange event in a input tag of type checkbox that calls a javascript function and pass three parameters from the model to the function:

```
<input type="checkbox" ... onchange="changeRow('@Model.Id', '@Model.Type', @Model.AwaitingApproval)" ...
```

In the changeRow javascript function the first two values are reported correctly, but the third parameter (which is of type boolean) is a reference to an onchange function. When inspecting the value, I can see the onchange function signature and it states that it is a function.

This is a normal MVC application with some jquery and the data is communicated through ajax calls from the controllers that serves the data through the Model.

If I change the code to the following:

```
<label>@Model.AwaitingApproval <input type="checkbox" ... onchange="changeRow('@Model.Id', '@Model.Type', @Model.AwaitingApproval)" ... </label>
```

Then the value TRUE is printed on the page before the checkbox. So, that proves that the model value is correct and can be referenced.

Any ideas on what might be causing the weird behavior in the js function would be greatly appreciated!
(Or an explanation of this behavior if it is expected and I am not understanding why this happens.)

Javascript function:

```
function changeRow(Id, Type, AwaitingApproval)
{
   if (!AwaitingApproval) (*This is where I first detected the problem*)
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

There is nothing "special" about the javascript function, it simply receives the parameters and then does processing based on the values.
The Id parameter has the correct integer value, the type field has the correct string value, but the AwaitingApproval parameter has the following:

```
function onchange(event)
{
   changeRow('7334512', 'targeted', onchange)
}
```

Which is basically the reference to the function I have assigned to the onchange event in the first place, and you guessed it, the onchange in the third parameter is yet another reference to the same function, causing an endless reference loop in the same way.

Comment: Show your `changeRow()` function.

Comment: @Stephen - I have added more information on the javascript code and the problem I have there. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some more playing, I thought to give it a try by enclosing the third parameter in a code block:

```
onchange="changeRow('@Model.Id', '@Model.Type', '@{ @Model.AwaitingApproval }')"
```

which then results in the correct boolean value stored in the property.

I do not understand this behavior at all and would love if someone can shed some light on this.

A *cleaner* way as suggested by **Stephen Muecke**

```
onchange="changeRow('@Model.Id', '@Model.Type', '@Model.AwaitingApproval.ToString()')"
```

It is important to remember the quotes and then test for *string* values ('True' / 'False') in the javascript function.

Comment: I doubt this will work is `AwaitingApproval` is `false`

Comment: Just tested and it wont - your would need to use `'@Model.AwaitingApproval.ToString()'`. And then test if its "True" or "False". But you would be far better off getting rid of the (awful) `onchange()` and using [unobtrusive javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) - `$(yourCheckBox).change(function() { .... });`

Comment: That's strange, because the answer as I have it, works both for True and False. I do apologize, because I have a typo in there, the code block should be wrapped in quotes.
I like your suggestion to use unobtrusive js for event binding, but this is code I have to do maintenance on and there are no unobtrusive js event binding done, so I would like to stick to a "standard" and unfortunately that standard for this project is attribute event binding on the tag. I have fixed the "typo" to reflect exactly what I have at the moment.

Comment: Yes, quoting it would work (its the equivalent of what I suggested) but you will need to test for a `string` not a `boolean`

Comment: Yes, I have adapted the js function accordingly, I would just like to know the "mechanics" behind this and why razor behaves in this way. Mainly the need for the codeblock around the boolean parameter and why I end up with a function reference if I do not do it this way.

Comment: You don't need the code block. What you need is the quotes, otherwise your effectively providing an undefined variable to the function (and to test, remove the quotes around `@Model.Type` and you will see the resulting error in the console)

Comment: Without the code block it does not work. If I have it as only:
onchange="changeRow('@Model.Id', '@Model.Type', '@Model.AwaitingApproval')" this, then I get "onchange" in the js function as the value and not "True" or "False". That is the original problem.

Comment: It does work, but you need the `.ToString()` as I noted previously. But either way is fine :)

Comment: lol, sorry. You are right. Thanks again for your time and input. I appreciate it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - If you post your suggestion as an answer, I will accept that, as it is "cleaner" than using the code block. I still don't understand why it is needed, though. I do understand converting a boolean to string will give you a string value, but I don't understand why .ToString is needed for the boolean and not for the integer Model.Id field.

Comment: No need for me to post an answer, you can just modify yours to include both options.

Comment: Point of info:  The code block DOES work in Chrome v56.x if you have quotes around it as shown above.  But it certainly is cleaner to use ToString(), as shown, especially when making the comparison in javascript where you compare the value - since you compare to a string:  if (awaitingApproval === 'True') {}

Answer (score 0):

In your first example `<input type="checkbox" ... onchange="changeRow('@Model.Id', '@Model.Type', @Model.AwaitingApproval)" ...` you have your `@Model.AwaitingApproval` parameter without `''`. So maybe try `onchange="changeRow('@Model.Id', '@Model.Type', '@Model.AwaitingApproval')"`

Comment: That was on purpose, in order to explain that I get a reference to the onchange function reference. If I use your suggested fix, I get "onchange" as a string value instead of the bollean property value.